# SQLITE3 Insert into the most recent row where 1 column is an exact match

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this fairly large DB. It contains lots of column. One of the will have a value that I need to select, but the DB has several of that value. How can I insert into a column in the row thats the newest in the DB, with a matching column.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the ins and outs of your database, I think you would likely want to select the largest id you have in the auto incrementing row. For instance:

SELECT MAX(UNIQUE_ID) FROM TABLE WHERE MATCHING_COLUMN = MATCHING_VALUE

From there you can take your unique ID and insert into that row.